# How do I form a suds request in Python using a WSDL that uses the "any" type?

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, suds

Note, this is not a duplicate of [How to pass "Any" type parameter in SOAP request using zeep in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189479/how-to-pass-any-type-parameter-in-soap-request-using-zeep-in-python).

This question relates to using suds, the other to zeep, and the problem and issues encountered are different.

I have a WSDL that uses the "any" type for the core element (Element) in all SOAP operations. Note that I have trimmed this down as it's quite big.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:xtk:queryDef" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:xtk:queryDef" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:xtk:queryDef">
        <s:complexType name="Element">
            <s:sequence>
                <s:any processContents="lax"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="ExecuteQuery">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="sessiontoken" type="s:string" />
            <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="entity" type="tns:Element" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ExecuteQueryResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="pdomOutput" type="tns:Element" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="ExecuteQueryIn">
    <part element="tns:ExecuteQuery" name="parameters" />
  </message>
  <message name="ExecuteQueryOut">
    <part element="tns:ExecuteQueryResponse" name="parameters" />
  </message>
  <portType name="queryDefMethodsSoap">
    <operation name="ExecuteQuery">
      <input message="tns:ExecuteQueryIn" />
      <output message="tns:ExecuteQueryOut" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
<binding name="queryDefMethodsSoap" type="tns:queryDefMethodsSoap">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <operation name="ExecuteQuery">
    <soap:operation soapAction="xtk:queryDef#ExecuteQuery" style="document" />
    <input>
      <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal" />
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal" />
    </output>
  </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="XtkQueryDef">
      <port binding="tns:queryDefMethodsSoap" name="queryDefMethodsSoap">
        <soap:address location="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/nl/jsp/soaprouter.jsp" />
      </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I cannot seem to form the correct parameters to call the `ExecuteQuery` service using suds-jurko in Python 3.

I want to send the equivalent of this payload:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:xtk:queryDef">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ExecuteQuery>
         <urn:sessiontoken>xxxxxxx</urn:sessiontoken>
         <urn:entity>
            <queryDef schema="nms:recipient" operation="select">
              <select>
                <node expr="@email"/>
                <node expr="@lastName+'-'+@firstName"/>
                <node expr="Year(@birthDate)"/>
              </select>
              <orderBy>
                <node expr="@birthDate" sortDesc="true"/>
              </orderBy>
        </queryDef>
         </urn:entity>
      </urn:ExecuteQuery>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I have this code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from suds.client import Client
import os


# Executes a query and returns the result set
def execute_query():
    # Load the WSDL locally - not authorised to get from server
    wsdl_url = urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.abspath("querydef_dev.wsdl")))
    session_token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

    # Init the client
    query_client = Client(wsdl_url)

    # Construct the query def
    query_def = {
            "queryDef": {
                "select": {
                    "node": [
                        {
                            "_expr": "@email"
                        },
                        {
                            "_expr": "@lastName+'-'+@firstName"
                        },
                        {
                            "_expr": "Year(@birthDate)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "orderBy": {
                    "node": {
                        "_expr": "@birthDate",
                        "_sortDesc": "true"
                    }
                },
                "_schema": "nms:recipient",
                "_operation": "select"
            }
        }

    try:
        response = query_client.service.ExecuteQuery(sessiontoken=session_token, entity=query_def)
    except:
        print("Failed!")
    print(query_client.last_sent())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute_query()
```

However, that results in an incorrect XML payload that messes with the attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:xtk:queryDef">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:ExecuteQuery>
         <ns1:sessiontoken>xxxxxxxxxxx</ns1:sessiontoken>
         <ns1:entity>
            <ns1:queryDef>
               <ns1:select>
                  <ns1:node>
                     <ns1:_expr>@email</ns1:_expr>
                  </ns1:node>
                  <ns1:node>
                     <ns1:_expr>@lastName+&apos;-&apos;+@firstName</ns1:_expr>
                  </ns1:node>
                  <ns1:node>
                     <ns1:_expr>Year(@birthDate)</ns1:_expr>
                  </ns1:node>
               </ns1:select>
               <ns1:orderBy>
                  <ns1:node>
                     <ns1:_expr>@birthDate</ns1:_expr>
                     <ns1:_sortDesc>true</ns1:_sortDesc>
                  </ns1:node>
               </ns1:orderBy>
               <ns1:_schema>nms:recipient</ns1:_schema>
               <ns1:_operation>select</ns1:_operation>
            </ns1:queryDef>
         </ns1:entity>
      </ns1:ExecuteQuery>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

There is no complexType definition of "Element" that I can use with `client.factory.create`, so I'm stuck as to how I form the payload I need.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77189479/20851944) question makes it not more clear!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass "Any" type parameter in SOAP request using zeep in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189479/how-to-pass-any-type-parameter-in-soap-request-using-zeep-in-python)

Comment: The two questions are different. One is using suds, one using zeep. The problem and challenges are different.